# Logging Verbosity not in TfvcTemplate12

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Looking at the build process files, I don't see the Logging Verbosity parameter in the TfvcTemplate.12. even though it is in the Upgrade template. Is there a reason why? I was reading the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh190720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for 2012 that logging verbosity was in the Default template there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build logs in TFS2013 are much more comprehensive by default than in previous versions (especially in the web client!). As a result, Microsoft probably felt that logging verbosity wasn't really a necessary configurable setting -- you can drill in and get more detail if you want it.

In fact, if you go to "Diagnostics" -> "View Logs" when viewing a build from Visual Studio, it will kick you over to web access and show you the detailed, diagnostic-level logs for that build.